# Why can I receive ethernet frames bigger than my current MTU size?

Tags: linux, mtu

I configured the MTU size to 1000 with `ip link set eth0 mtu 1000` on link eth0. 
I disabled Generic receiving offloading (gro) with `ethtool -K gro off` (since this can lead to "false" frame length in tcpdump ([see here](https://www.myricom.com/software/myri10ge/349-when-i-view-traffic-with-tcpdump-why-do-i-see-packets-larger-than-the-mtu.html))) 
But if I capture now with tcpdump I still get packets which are larger than 1000, e.g. 1500 bytes.

What I am doing wrong ?

On the receiving side with MTU set to 1000:

> eth0:  mtu 1000
>
> 14:27:38.361168 IP XXXXXX > YYYYYY: ICMP echo > request, id 3273, seq
>   1, **length 1480**  14:27:38.361495 IP YYYYYY > XXXXXX: ICMP echo reply,
>   id 3273, seq 1, length 976

Answer (score 7):

MTU is the maximum packet size that can be **sent** through an interface. MTU doesn't limit the maximum packet size that can be received.

[RFC 1191](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1191/) says:

> ...   When one IP host has a large amount of data to send to another
>   host,    the data is transmitted as a series of IP datagrams.  It is
>   usually    preferable that these datagrams be of the largest size that
>   does not    require fragmentation anywhere along the path from the
>   source to the    destination.  (For the case against fragmentation,
>   see [5].)  This    datagram size is referred to as the Path MTU
>   (PMTU), and it is equal    to the minimum of the MTUs of each hop in
>   the path.  A shortcoming of    the current Internet protocol suite is
>   the lack of a standard    mechanism for a host to discover the PMTU of
>   an arbitrary path.
>
> ```
>       Note: The Path MTU is what in [1] is called the "Effective MTU
>       for sending" (EMTU_S).  A PMTU is associated with a path,
>       which is a particular combination of IP source and destination
>       address and perhaps a Type-of-service (TOS)...
> ```

Comment: I read that both sides should have the same MTU. But if the MTU is only the maximum sending size, the MTU's of both can be different ? Additional, can I configure the maximum receiving unit size in my Linux ?

Comment: Further I ask myself how could I then discover which size the other connection side can receive ? I mean MTU is for sending. Can I determine the Maximum receiving unit size of my counterpart?

Comment: As MTU affects only outgoing packets, in general it could be different at both sides. In my opinion, in this case each side will use is own MTU for sending packets, but I'm not 100% sure if both sides will use the smaller MTU instead. MRU is dinamically set after negotiation, I think it couldn´t be manually set.

Comment: @der_wolle There isn't any way for the receiver to communicate to the sender what the MRU is. If the MRU of an interface was less than the MTU of any other interface on the segment, you could be losing packets. It would be possible for a device to receive all packets regardless of size and respond with a "Too Big" response if it was larger than you wanted. But it would be mostly pointless to receive the packet and then reject it. For TCP you can control the sizes end-to-end through the MSS option, which by default is derived from the MTU of the endpoint.